# Solve Mathieu Equation $y''+(1+\epsilon \cdot \sin(3t))y=0, \;y(0)=u, \;y'(0)=v$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just need to know the solution to this differential equation. I tried wolfram alpha and some other online resources but none worked.

$$y''(t)+(1+\epsilon \cdot \sin(3t))y(t)=0, \; y(0)=u, \; y'(0)=v$$

Comment: My guess is that you'll be stuck with numerical methods.

Comment: ok. Thank you. I will look into that.

Comment: the solution is given by $$y \left( t \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{\it MathieuC} \left( 4/9,-2/9,-\pi /4
+3/2\,t \right) +{\it \_C2}\,{\it MathieuS} \left( 4/9,-2/9,-\pi /4+3/
2\,t \right) 
$$

Comment: Does that account for $\epsilon$ and the ICs?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thank you. What does the MathieuC and S mean?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. Could you replace your expression in the differential equation and tell what you get ? Certainly not $0$, I bet. Moreover, where did go $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @Math4Life : MathieuC and MathieuS are so called "Special Functions". This means known functions, which are referenced in the math. handbooks, which a lot of properties were discribed. For example :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function . About the use of special functions, a paper for general public : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: @JJacquelin. Hi Jean ! Even in terms of Mathieu functions, do you see a possible solution of the differential equation (including the $\epsilon$ term for sure) ? . Cheers.

Comment: Quite the result as in the Dr Sonnhard Graubner's comment, except that he forgot $\epsilon$ in the second parameter $-2\epsilon/9$ of the Mathieu functions. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+(1+\epsilon \sin(3t))y(t)=0 \tag 1$$
$t=\frac{2}{3}\tau \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{9}{4}\frac{d^2y}{d\tau^2}$ 
$$\frac{d^2y}{d\tau^2}+\left(\frac{4}{9}+\frac{4}{9}\epsilon \sin(2\tau)\right)y(\tau)=0$$
$\tau=x+\frac{\pi}{4} \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2y}{d\tau^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}  \quad $and$\quad \sin(2\tau)=\cos(2x)$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{4}{9}+\frac{4}{9}\epsilon \cos(2x)\right)y(x)=0$$
This is the Mathieu ODE : $\quad\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(a-2b \cos(2x)\right)y(x)=0\quad$ with $\begin{cases}a=\frac{4}{9}\\b=-\frac{2\epsilon}{9} \end{cases}$

The general solution involves the Mathieu functions :

$y(x)=c_1\text{MathieuC}(a,b,x)+c_2\text{MathieuS}(a,b,x)$
$$y(x)=c_1\text{MathieuC}\left(\frac{4}{9},-\frac{2\epsilon}{9},x\right)+
c_2\text{MathieuS}\left(\frac{4}{9},-\frac{2\epsilon}{9},x\right)$$
$$y(\tau)=c_1\text{MathieuC}\left(\frac{4}{9},-\frac{2\epsilon}{9},\tau-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+c_2\text{MathieuS}\left(\frac{4}{9},-\frac{2\epsilon}{9},\tau-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
The general solution of the ODE $(1)$ is :
$$y(t)=c_1\text{MathieuC}\left(\frac{4}{9}\:,\:-\frac{2\epsilon}{9}\:,\:\frac{3}{2}t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+c_2\text{MathieuS}\left(\frac{4}{9}\:,\:-\frac{2\epsilon}{9}\:,\:\frac{3}{2}t -\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

The coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ have to be determined according to the conditions $y(0)=u$ and $y'(0)=v$. This is theoeticaly possible, but in fact very arduous, due to the antiderivatives of the Mathieu functions which have no simple closed form.

NOTE :

If the real question is not to solve Eq.$(1)$ , but to find an approximate solution for small $\epsilon$ , the problem is very different. Using the exact solution in terms of Mathieu function is not a smart method. It would be a bad way, very complicated.

It is much simpler to expend $y(\epsilon,t)$ in power series of $\epsilon$ :
$$y(t)=f_0(t)+\epsilon f_1(t)+\epsilon^2 f_2(t)+...$$
Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ :

$(f_0''+\epsilon f_1''+\epsilon^2 f_2''+...)+(1+\epsilon \sin(3t))(f_0+\epsilon f_1+\epsilon^2 f_2+...)=0$

$(f_0''+f_0)+\epsilon \left(f_1''+f_1+\sin(3t)f_0\right)+\epsilon^2 \left(f_2''+f_2+\sin(3t)f_1\right)+...=0$

The first approximate is $y(t)\simeq f_0(t)$ with $\epsilon=0$ :

$f_0''(t)+f_0(t)=0$ with conditions $f_0(0)=u$ and $f_0'(0)=v\quad\to\quad $
$$f_0(t)=u\:\cos(t)+v\:\sin(t)$$

For the second approximate : $\quad f_1''+f_1+\sin(3t)f_0=0\quad$ with conditions $f_1(0)=f'_1(0)=0$ since the boundary conditions are already satisfied above.

$f_1''+f_1+\sin(3t)(u\:\cos(t)+v\:\sin(t))=0$

$$f_1(t)=-\frac{4}{15}\sin^3(t)\left(11u\cos{\frac{t}{2}}+3u\cos{\frac{3t}{2}}+u\cos{\frac{5t}{2}}+ v\sin{\frac{t}{2}}+3v\sin{\frac{3t}{2}}+v\sin{\frac{5t}{2}}\right)$$

$$y(t)\simeq u\:\cos(t)+v\:\sin(t) +\epsilon \:f_1(t)$$

For even better approximate, one could continue on the same way with $f_2''+f_2+\sin(3t)f_1=0$ and conditions $f_2(0)=f_2'(0)=0$.